# Convert multidimensional array to list of single array

Tags: c#

I have a multi dimensional array which i need to convert to a list of arrays. Not one single array, but for each iteration of the first dimension i need a separate array containing the values in the second dimension.

How do I convert this:

```
int[,] dummyArray = new int[,] { {1,2,3}, {4,5,6}};
```

into a `list<int[]>` holding two arrays with values `{1,2,3}` and `{4,5,6}`?

Comment: The keyword for this is "flatten" for online searches.

Comment: @BananaAcid, but OP not want `List<int>` he want `List<int[]>`

Comment: @Grundy: right, but how "flat" it should be - i believe, example code could be adjusted. Like the LINQ example link below, just takes the first "level" out of it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can convert 2d array into [jagged array](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2s05feca.aspx) and then [convert it to List](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb342261%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

```
int[,] arr = new int[,] { { 1, 2, 3 }, { 4, 5, 6 } };

int[][] jagged = new int[arr.GetLength(0)][];

for (int i = 0; i < arr.GetLength(0); i++)
{
    jagged[i] = new int[arr.GetLength(1)];
    for (int j = 0; j < arr.GetLength(1); j++)
    {
        jagged[i][j] = arr[i, j];
    }
}

List<int[]> list = jagged.ToList();
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use Linq:

```
int[,] dummyArray = new int[,] { { 1, 2, 3 }, { 4, 5, 6 } };
int count = 0;
List<int[]> list = dummyArray.Cast<int>()
                    .GroupBy(x => count++ / dummyArray.GetLength(1))
                    .Select(g => g.ToArray())
                    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use for loop like this:

```
        int[,] dummyArray = new int[,] { { 1, 2, 3 }, { 4, 5, 6 } };

        int size1 = dummyArray.GetLength(1);
        int size0 = dummyArray.GetLength(0);

        List<int[]> list = new List<int[]>();

        for (int i = 0; i < size0; i++)
        {
            List<int> newList = new List<int>();

            for (int j = 0; j < size1; j++)
            {
                newList.Add(dummyArray[i, j]);
            }

            list.Add(newList.ToArray());
        }
```

Comment: why not use array directly instead calling `ToArray` on list? you already know length, that not changed.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a reusable implementation

```
public static class Utils
{
    public static List<T[]> To1DArrayList<T>(this T[,] source)
    {
        if (source == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("source");
        int rowCount = source.GetLength(0), colCount = source.GetLength(1);
        var list = new List<T[]>(rowCount);
        for (int row = 0; row < rowCount; row++)
        {
            var data = new T[colCount];
            for (int col = 0; col < data.Length; col++)
                data[col] = source[row, col];
            list.Add(data);
        }
        return list;
    }
}
```

and sample usage

```
var source = new int[,] { { 1, 2, 3 }, { 4, 5, 6 } };
var result = source.To1DArrayList();
```

Some comments on other answers.

[M.kazem Akhgary](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4767498/m-kazem-akhgary): If I need a **list**, I don't see why should I first create **jagged array** and **convert** it to a **list** instead of creating **list** directly.

[Eser](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5149474/eser): I usually like his elegant Linq solutions, but this definitely is not one of them. If the idea is to use Linq (although I strongly believe it's not intended for that), the following would be much more appropriate:

```
var source = new int[,] { { 1, 2, 3 }, { 4, 5, 6 } };
var result = Enumerable.Range(0, source.GetLength(0))
    .Select(row => Enumerable.Range(0, source.GetLength(1))
    .Select(col => source[row, col]).ToArray())
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Yours should be the accepted answer, and I agree with your comments on other answers. I read those first (since they appear above yours) and my steam level was increasing until I finally saw your comments. ;)